# Apply a bootstrap template to a blazor webassembly with no breaking or losing any working features

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Is it possible to apply a template from https://bootstrapmade.com/ or any alternative without losing any feature ?

**what is the best practcies to do it successfully ?**

for example:

when appling template arsha.

[image]

A lot of things work but oppening the nav menu on mobile version not working !
Other templates other things work and other don't.

somtimes Invoke main.js then Some features works.

```
  protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
    JS.InvokeVoidAsync("main");
}
```

**Is there a way to make the template fully works inside blazor webassemple ?**

Comment: The main problem you face is where JS functionality is being used to control the template.  This often conflicts with the Blazor RenderTree and causes all sorts of tricky problems.  If it's pure HTML and CSS then you're normally OK.  The more JS, the more likely the answer is no.

Comment: Would you please explain the reason. @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: Blazor maintains a virtual DOM which it uses to write changes to the browser display.  If a framework manipulates that browser display separately - maybe changing class data - then the display and the Blazor DOM are out of sync.  The next Dom write may then override the framework changes.