# How to use open source Bootstrap templates and use JQuery or JS library in Blazor Server

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I want to use a Bootstrap template from github that uses jquery and other js packages.

**I am using this template** https://zuramai.github.io/mazer/

I am familiar with this template and have been using this in many projects in ASP.Net Core. Now I have started to learn Blazor and want to do a project but **I'm really bad at css and designing** So I prefer to use templates or hire a designer to design a webpage and use JQuery for DOM manipulation.

**I tried to add the js files used in the template in my blazor.**

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@namespace SreaFrame.BlazorServer.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="~/" />
    @*<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />*@
    @*<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    @*<link href="SreaFrame.BlazorServer.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />*@
    <link rel="shortcut icon"
          href="mazer/assets/compiled/svg/favicon.svg"
          type="image/x-icon" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mazer/assets/compiled/css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mazer/assets/compiled/css/app-dark.css" />

    <component type="typeof(HeadOutlet)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
</head>
<body>

    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>

    <script src="mazer/assets/static/js/components/dark.js"></script>
    <script src="mazer/assets/extensions/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>

    <script src="mazer/assets/compiled/js/app.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

**I would be Ok for me if the manipulation of Data DOM is not possible but changing the state of div such as Dropdown click or Collapse of Sidebar would be really helpful to develop a system being Backend Developer.
**

I tried researching and got to know that we cannot use other tools to manipulate DOM as this might cause conflict in Blazor States.

**This is question that I read **
[Apply a bootstrap template to a blazor webassembly with no breaking or losing any working features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351217/apply-a-bootstrap-template-to-a-blazor-webassembly-with-no-breaking-or-losing-an#comment120800492_68351217)

I wanted to know if there is any other way to use library such as Jquery or JqueryUI and use templates designed by other developers.

Also I would like to get some suggestion on if there is resources that will help me in improving designs and function in Blazor app.

Comment: You said you "tried adding the js files used in the template", so what happened next? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I added the js files from the template the template features functions such as Dark mode and light mode which is not working also the sidebar toggle button is not working as well as the showing multi level menu is not working on click action.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? In your Dev Console perhaps?

Comment: No not any console is all clean

Comment: @mxmissile I have also checked if the network is calling the js files or not and js files has been loaded perfectly in the network tab

Answer (score 0):

I am also using the Mazer template in a .Net solution.

In both a Blazor Server and Blazor Webassembly solution, the behavior is the same as reported by you.

What I've discovered so far is that if I put all the Sidebar and Header DIVs inside the _Host.cshtml file, it works perfectly.

The problem occurs when I separate these code snippets into specific razor components, then it stops working.